# Why does the order of replacing things matter in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I have a file like this:

```
(paren)
[sharp]
```

And I try to replace like this:

```
sed "s/(/[/g" some_file.txt
```

And it works just fine:

```
[paren)
[sharp]
```

Then I try to replace like this:

```
sed "s/[/(/g" some_file.txt
```

And it gives me the error:

```
sed: 1: "s/[/(/g": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

I cannot find any evidence as to why this would error out.  Why does the order of `[` and `(` matter?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If `man sed` doesn't provide enough info then google `sed` and read any tutorial on it.

Answer (score 4):

The `[` is a part of a [*bracket expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) that must have  a closing counterpart (`]`).

Escape the `[` to match a literal `[` symbol:

```
echo "[sharp]" | sed 's/\[/(/g'
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/yGVvvn)

Comment: As for *Why does the order of `[` and `(` matter?*, it is not actually about the order, but what the replacement sed command is made of. Andrew describes that, but here is my addition: `s` is the *replacement* action, then comes a *POSIX regex pattern* (if you have `(`, it is treated as a literal `(`, but `[` is a part of a bracket expression, so there must be a closing `]` for the pattern to be valid), then a *replacement pattern* (just a *string* that may contain backreferences, but not a regex pattern), and then a *flag* (or *modifier*) (here, `g` - global replacement of all matches).

Answer (score 2):

The reason it matters is because you're replacing a regex with a literal string.
So the bracket is viewed as a character when used after the second slash. It is viewed as part of an invalid regex when used between the first and second slash.

So in this expression the '[' is taken as a character:

`s/(/[/g`

In this expression it's not:

`s/[/(/g`

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter in a replacement with sed must be a regex pattern:
`s/regex_pattern/replacement_string/`

The opening square bracket has a special meaning in a regex pattern, since it is the beginning of a character class, for example `[a-z]`. That is why you obtain this error message that has nothing to do with the order of your replacements: `unbalanced brackets ([])` *(an opened character class must be closed.)*

To obtain a literal opening square bracket, you need to escape it: `\[`

```
sed 's/\[/(/' file
```

If your goal is to translate characters into others, there is a more simple way, using a translation, that avoids the problem of circular replacements:

```
a='(paren)
[sharp]'
```

using `tr`

```
echo "$a" | tr '[]()' '()[]'
```

or with `sed`:

```
echo "$a" | sed 'y/[]()/()[]/'
```